# Class python in loop

Tags: python, class

I created a class of matrix with python:

```
class MatrixOperation:

    ...

    def create_matrix(self):
        some function for creation of matrix.
        return matrix

    def matrix_vector_multiplication(self, x):
        mat = self.create_matrix()
        return numpy.dot(mat, x)
```

And:

```
M = MatrixOperation(...)
x = some set of vector

for i in range(n):
   M.matrix_vector_multiplication(x[i])
```

The problem is, for each iteration, `M.matrix_vector_multiplication(x[i])` will recompute `mat = self.create_matrix()` before calculating `numpy.dot(mat, x)`, that is unnecessary (since it could be computed once at the beginning). How can I avoid this?

Thanks,

Comment: Should `create_matrix` *return* the matrix, or could it make it an instance attribute?

Comment: What do you mean `once`? by instance? by process like static variable in Java?

Comment: I mean the matrix was created in the first iteration. For the 2, 3... iteration, I just do matrix_vector_multiplication, do not repeat the creation of matrix.

Answer (score 3):

To avoid recreating the matrix each time, create an instance attribute in the class's `__init__` method - similar to this.

```
class Matrix(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.matrix = self.create_matrix(data)
        # or simply
        # self.matrix = np.matrix(data)
    def create_matrix(data):
        # create the_matrix
        return the_matrix
    def do_something(self, x):
        z = some_function(self.matrix, x)
        return z

my_matrix = matrix([[1,2,3,4],[4,3,2,1]])
```

Comment: Here's a good read - https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects

Answer (score 1):

just making a copy of the matrix should fix your problem.

```
import copy


class MatrixOperation:
matrix = None
...

def create_matrix(self):
    if self.matrix is not None:
        return copy.copy(self.matrix)
    some function for creation of matrix.
    self.matrix = matrix
    return matrix

def matrix_vector_multiplication(self, x):
    mat = self.create_matrix()
    return numpy.dot(mat, x)
```